# Catching C++ exceptions when multiple Python modules share one C++ .so

Tags: c++, exception, cpython

I have a piece of python code that's structured like this:

```
import A
import B

A.throw()
B.throw()
```

Both `A` and `B` are modules written in C++. When I compile them, both of them link to a common library `exception.so`, which includes an exception and a function that raises it:

```
class MyException {};
void raise_exception() {
    throw MyException(); 
}
```

The `A.cxx` and `B.cxx` files contain the following lines within the python wrapper function `throw()`:

```
try {
    raise_exception(); 
} catch (const MyException& ) { 
    std::cout << "caught" << std::endl; 
}
```

Everything compiles fine, and both `A` and `B` work fine on their own.

The strange thing happens when I load both modules: the exception is only caught by `A` if `import A` comes first. Likewise, `B` is only able to catch the exception if `B` is loaded first. I need both the modules to work at the same time, and obviously I want the C++ exceptions to be caught within the C++ routines so they won't terminate the overlying python script. Any ideas about how to accomplish this?

**Edit:** It may be possible to include `raise_exception()` in a python [capsule](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#using-capsules), but this seems like overkill given that `exception.so` is never loaded as a python module (it does, however, use some code from libpython.so). Given that many python modules make use of system headers, it seems like including a user built C++ library would be trivial.

Comment: Probably need more details. Are you using boost python? Static or dynamic linking, etc?

Comment: @01100110 more details: using the python api directly (boost, SWIG won't work within the framework), static linking, problem exists whether I use gcc 4.1 or 4.3 (haven't checked more recent versions), working with linux

Comment: This sounds as though the `typeinfo`s for MyException aren't equal (don't compare equal) in A.so and B.so, so that the `catch()` fails to identify the exception type in the failing module. Are you sure that they share the same exception.so (in the runtime image)? You might try to print the `typeid(MyException)` for both modules.

Comment: I've tried printing `typeid(MyException).name()` as suggested by @modelnine, they are the same for both classes. How to I check to make sure they share the same exception.so in the runtime image?